# How about creating "Most Recommended Question (MRQ)" list

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This question was inspired by the recent question on HNQ:

[Allow mods or gold tag badge holders to prevent question from being on hot network questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284929/allow-mods-or-gold-tag-badge-holders-to-prevent-question-from-being-on-hot-netwo)

I am not an expert on computer or software and I was not aware how HNQ has been decided. But I do enjoy reading HNQs in the list.

What's your opinion on creating "Most Recommended Question" list where each site can show:

1. Very well asked question which can be an example question (well-researched and very helpful) for current and future users.
2. Very well answered question (even though a question is not well received) which can show each site can generate an excellent answer.

This list can be made by giving far higher weighting to high-rep users and moderators who can decide better which question is well asked and answered. It can be updated every week, two weeks or month. It would be better if the list could be kept on each site for the record even if it is removed from the MRQ list for update.

The reasons I suggest this idea are basically

1. The list could be different from HNQ as it will be decided by different weighting. As I commented to the linked question above, I sometimes felt embarrassed when I saw a poorly-researched, unhelpful, and even potentially off-topic question appear on the HNQ list. I know it is rare.
2. I am not 100% sure, but I have not seen many HNQs from a new beta site. I wonder whether it is due to very low activity of a beta site, or a beta site question is not eligible for HNQ. It could be used for promotion for new sites. They badly need inter-SE promotion for more traffic.
3. I think it is time SE considered giving a different upvote and downvote score depending on users' reputation. It could be controversial, but I feel there are too many blind votes cast by low-rep users.
4. I also believe it is time SE considered cancelling the upvoting privilege to 101 (association bonus) reputation users. They sometimes (I am guilty, too) go to some sites (especially new) and vote without knowing well whether a question or answer is well-researched and really helpful.

Thoughts, please?