# Hot Network Question is macabre. What are the standards for Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, hot-questions, sidebar, reporting

Not sure how I report/flag a "hot network question" or even if I have the reputation to.  However, the "[Husband stepped on cats head now she hates him](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27458/husband-stepped-on-cats-head-now-she-hates-him])" question is on the "Hot Network Questions" sidebar.

However, the discussion of animal abuse in the question is somewhat macabre.  Does this qualify to be removed from Hot Network Questions?  I can't remember how to report items in the sidebar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we flag questions with content/trigger warnings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317308/can-we-flag-questions-with-content-trigger-warnings) - similar case, with a graphic HNQ about an abused cat

Comment: A note to others: this question was [accidentally double posted](/q/346336). I've [filed a bug report about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346338/new-question-asking-form-sometimes-leads-to-accidental-double-posts-of-questions), since I've run into the same issue in the past.

Comment: Nice clickbait title :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can report them by flagging the question for ♦ moderator attention. Since a year, they have the ability to [remove questions from the Hot Network Questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/295232):

> #### Moderators have the ability to remove questions from the HNQ List.
>
> There are times when the hotness formula selects a question that a site would rather not have featured. Up until now, the only recourse that was available was to close the question (which may be appropriate anyway but isn't ideal when done purely to manage traffic), or to do nothing. We're putting the power in the hands of our moderators to remove questions that don't set a good example for their sites. I recommend each site have a meta discussion with guidance for moderators about when - if ever - a question should be removed.

Note that they might not immediately agree with you; you should use the flag message to convince them.

Comment: "even if I have the reputation to"...how does one go about doing so if one doesn't have enough rep to flag?

Comment: @Sonic raise the issue on main Meta since it's a network-wide problem, and will gather the amount of eyes necessary to take action

Comment: @Sonic I guess one could open a question on the site's own Meta (that requires 5 rep, not 15). Otherwise, what do you do when you want to report an offensive question without enough reputation? The only viable option I know of it the Contact Us form, but that's too slow ...

Comment: @Jenayah That requires 5 reputation on the site, so it's not ideal for someone who noticed on an external site, doesn't have enough rep for an association bonus, and wants to raise an issue.

Comment: @Sonic yeah, that's why I said to report on **main** Meta. Only 1 rep needed here

Comment: @Jenayah Sorry; I meant to ping Glorfindel in my comment instead of you.

Comment: @Sonic If no one with a assoc bonus thinks to flag a particular HNQ question, it seems that it isn't sufficiently problematic. The assoc bonus is pretty low hanging fruit.

Comment: The question has now been removed from HNQ (by a different mod from the one who answered it).