# Was there a brief system glitch which caused some questions to be posted twice?

Tags: bug, duplication

On Math SE, I saw there were 2 questions from 2 different users which were both repeated about a minute apart from each other, interlaced among each other, as shown below:

[image: Image showing 2 questions each repeated shortly after one another]

In case anybody wishes to check on the details of any of them, the 4 questions in the order shown are [When are the Eigenvectors of a A and $A^T$ the same?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820341/602049), [Find an equation in spherical coordinates for the surface represented by the rectangular equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820340/602049), https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820339/602049 (note: currently deleted), and [Find an equation in spherical coordinates for the surface represented by the rectangular equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3820338/602049).

It's possible each user just simply tried accidentally posting more than once, but this seems to occur quite rarely from my experience, and for this to happen with 2 users at basically the same time seems quite unlikely. Also, as for [Sonic the Masked Werehog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-masked-werehog)'s suggested duplicate of [New question asking form sometimes leads to accidental double posts of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346338/562482), I believe that most often occurs with the 2 questions posted at basically the same time as each other, but both of the 2 duplicates here were each posted about a minute apart from their earlier one, so I'm not sure if it's the same issue.

I checked the list of recent SO questions from around that same time, but didn't see any duplicate questions, exact or otherwise, occurring from the same user, although it's possible any such duplicates were already deleted. Nonetheless, is this something anyone else also saw around that time? Does anybody know if the SE system may have caused these repeats to occur rather than it being due to the users themselves?

Note I will check those posts sometime later and, if either user gives feedback as to something they did which may have caused these duplicates, I'll update this post with those details.

**Update:** After about 2 weeks, neither user of the duplicated questions has indicated anything, nobody has reported anything similar happening elsewhere, and there's been no official feedback. Note the 1st & 3rd questions shown above were posted 1 minute & 6 seconds apart, while the 2nd & 4th questions were posted 1 minute & 8 seconds apart. On rereading the suggested duplicate post, I realize a situation described there of initially double-clicking on the Review button and then shortly afterwards clicking on it again may cause the question to be posted twice, with each one being about a minute apart. As such, I am now fairly certain this is just the same issue, with these 2 sets of duplicates occurring so close together in time being just a coincidence.

Comment: The two questions were posted by the same user. It seems to be another instance of [New question asking form sometimes leads to accidental double posts of questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346338/new-question-asking-form-sometimes-leads-to-accidental-double-posts-of-questions)