# Prevent comment duplication

Tags: feature-request, comments

Possibly due to an internet connection problem I posted a couple of comments with the same content.

Staff can check it [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12591/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE?noredirect=1#comment54624_12591). The latter one was already deleted by me.

My proposal is to check the comment's content and prevent posting the same from the same user within a short time duration to prevent duplication.

A similar feature as far as I know was implemented in Twitter a long time ago.

Comment: I've had this a few times in connection with network glitches. The UI tells me something like "this comment could not be submitted at this time" and then when I click "Add comment" again, it reveals that the previous submission actually worked after all.