# Why did posting once end up with two posts?

Tags: support, technology, duplication

I posted a question on a stack exchange site. It ended up with two identical posts.

- After typing the post in the edit box, I don't think I hit the post button twice.
- Even if I hit the post button twice without the webpage navigated away in between, is Stack Exchange not able to detect the two requests are redundant?

The problem happened to me at least twice in the past months. I was wondering why? I am interested in knowing

- the possible reason from the technical perspective, e.g. cache inconsistency in a distributed system, and
- some possible technical solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: Repro here. I've seen this a couple of times on various sites and had it happen to myself when posting comments perhaps a couple of times over the years. It may be rare, but is symptomatic of something or other.

Comment: It's a known issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346338/sometimes-two-identical-copies-of-the-same-question-get-posted-at-the-same-time. (I accidentally voted for the wrong duplicate; I've removed that close vote but it means I can't vote for the correct one.)